# All possible combinations of N objects in K buckets

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation, enumeration

Suppose I have 3 boxes labeled A, B, C and I have 2 balls, B1 and B2. I want to get all possible combinations of these balls in the boxes. Please note, it is important to know which ball is in each box, meaning B1 and B2 are not the same.

```
A         B         C
B1, B2
B1        B2
B1                  B2
B2        B1        
B2                  B1
          B1, B2
          B1        B2
          B2        B1
                    B1, B2
```

#### Edit

If there is a known algorithm for this problem, please tell me its name.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Fixed. I was originally giving an example for 2 boxes, changed it to 3 for more clarity. But I know for a fact that you knew that and wanted to be cute. So there you go.

Comment: Do you need all the permutations or just the total count?

Comment: I take every chance I get :) There are (number of boxes)^(number of balls) such combinations. Do you want to list them all or do you want to access a particular combination?

Comment: @AKSingh I need all the permutations

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I need all of them. I need to apply a heuristic function on them and add some computation on each one of them

Comment: `n` distinguishable objects and `m` distinguishable bins: objects are independent from each other. There are `m` ways to put the first object. Similarly for the second, `m^n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very simple recursive implementation that at each level adds the current ball to each box. The recursion ends when all balls have been processed.

Here's some Java code to illustrate. We use a `Stack` to represent each box so we can simply pop the last-added ball after each level of recursion.

```
void boxBalls(List<Stack<String>> boxes, String[] balls, int i)
{
    if(i == balls.length)
    {
        System.out.println(boxes);
        return;
    }
    
    for(Stack<String> box : boxes)
    {
        box.push(balls[i]);
        boxBalls(boxes, balls, i+1);
        box.pop();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
String[] balls = {"B1", "B2"};
List<Stack<String>> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) boxes.add(new Stack<>());

boxBalls(boxes, balls, 0);
```

Output:

```
[[B1, B2], [], []]
[[B1], [B2], []]
[[B1], [], [B2]]
[[B2], [B1], []]
[[], [B1, B2], []]
[[], [B1], [B2]]
[[B2], [], [B1]]
[[], [B2], [B1]]
[[], [], [B1, B2]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Very simple solution. I wish I could select both answers but I generally don't like recursive functions unless I have to. That's the only reason I'm picking the other solution but your solution is very easier to follow. Thanks again.

Comment: I take it back. Because your solution was more simple and it used Stack for the same objects it ran way faster than the other algorithm. I'm picking this one.

Comment: This solution with recursion looks amazingly simple.
Could anybody suggest a solution that would not print the boxes but the boxes would be returned by some "Next" function one by one? So the caller of this algorithm with "Next" function could get permutations one by one.

Answer (score 4):

Let `N` be number of buckets (`3` in the example), `M` number of balls (`2`). Now, let's have a look at numbers in a range `[0..N**M)` - `[0..9)` in the example; these numbers we represent with `radix = N`. For the example in the question we have *trinary* numbers

Now we can easily interprete these numbers: first digit shows 1st ball location, second - 2nd ball position.

```
      |--- Second Ball position [0..2]
      ||-- First Ball position  [0..2]  
      ||
  0 = 00 - both balls are in the bucket #0 (`A`)
  1 = 01 - first ball is in the bucket #1 ('B'), second is in the bucket #0 (`A`)
  2 = 02 - first ball is in the bucket #2 ('C'), second is in the bucket #0 (`A`)
  3 = 10 - first ball is in the bucket #0 ('A'), second is in the bucket #1 (`B`)
  4 = 11 - both balls are in the bucket #1 (`B`)
  5 = 12 ...
  6 = 20
  7 = 21 ...
  8 = 22 - both balls are in the bucket #2 (`C`)
```

the general algorithm is:

1. For each number in `0 .. N**M` range
2. `i`th ball (`i = 0..M-1`) will be in the bucket # `(number / N**i) % N` (here `/` stands for *integer* division, `%` for remainder)

If you want just total count, the answer is simple `N ** M`, in the example above `3 ** 2 == 9`

**C# Code** The algorithm itself is easy to implement:

```
static IEnumerable<int[]> BallsLocations(int boxCount, int ballCount) {
  BigInteger count = BigInteger.Pow(boxCount, ballCount);

  for (BigInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    int[] balls = new int[ballCount];
    int index = 0;

    for (BigInteger value = i; value > 0; value /= boxCount)
      balls[index++] = (int)(value % boxCount);

    yield return balls;
  }
}
```

It's answer representation which can be entangled:

```
static IEnumerable<string> BallsSolutions(int boxCount, int ballCount) {
  foreach (int[] balls in BallsLocations(boxCount, ballCount)) {
    List<int>[] boxes = Enumerable
      .Range(0, boxCount)
      .Select(_ => new List<int>())
      .ToArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < balls.Length; ++j)
      boxes[balls[j]].Add(j + 1);

    yield return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, boxes
      .Select((item, index) => $"Box {index + 1} : {string.Join(", ", item.Select(b => $"B{b}"))}"));
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  int balls = 3;
  int boxes = 2;

  string report = string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine + "------------------" + Environment.NewLine, 
    BallsSolutions(boxes, balls));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Box 1 : B1, B2, B3
Box 2 : 
------------------
Box 1 : B2, B3
Box 2 : B1
------------------
Box 1 : B1, B3
Box 2 : B2
------------------
Box 1 : B3
Box 2 : B1, B2
------------------
Box 1 : B1, B2
Box 2 : B3
------------------
Box 1 : B2
Box 2 : B1, B3
------------------
Box 1 : B1
Box 2 : B2, B3
------------------
Box 1 : 
Box 2 : B1, B2, B3
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1QQMrH)

Comment: Are the bounds in the pseudocode inclusive? I tried it but it's missing some cases. Please [check this implementation of it in C#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ar5Qkf)

Comment: @Alireza Noori: please see my edit (C# code instead of pseudocode) and fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/1QQMrH The algorithm itself is easy, but it takes time to represent its answer in the desired way

Comment: Thank you very much. The new edit got it fixed

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer because it explains the conceptual approach. With that, the code is almost irrelevant!